# Working with one table from two applications (caching issues) with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have two web-applications (Frontend and Backend).

[image: Applications]

Both applications share the same database.

On development environment (debug) I launch both simultaneously.
[image: Two Application Run]

When debugging, if I change value of any field in BackEnd, on FrontEnd changes are not applied. In the database values ​​are changed. (**ie `Update` passed**, `SELECT` from Management Studio gives the correct data)

*My guess is that on FrontEnd EF stores a local copy of the data.*

**Changes appear (on FrontEnd) only when I restarted debug.**

A code example for FrontEnd:

```
using (company_unitEntities _fc = new company_unitEntities())
{
    var ff = _fc.agency_tamplates_d.ToList();
}
```

**Interesting Fact:**

When I add `AsNoTracking` method to data load, and watched Prifiler, I discovered that 'SELECT` queries arrive at the server, but the changes do not appear.

```
using (company_unitEntities _fc = new company_unitEntities())
{
    var ff = _fc.agency_tamplates_d.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

[image: Profiler]

What could be the reason for such behavior EF?

---

I use:
*ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework*

Thank you!

**UPD:**
FrontEnd and BackEnd use different Entity Data Model.

Comment: Unless you are doing edit and continue I'm not sure why you think code changes would automatically be applied. Naturally you have to recompile and restart.

Comment: Recompile every time I want to retrieve data from the database? You must be joking.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were making table/schema changes, not just data changes. I misread. Yes, EF does cache queries

Comment: How is it possible to worked simultaneously two applications with the same database  using the EF? Disable cache? Use one Entity Data Model? Thanks..

Comment: I had a similar issue, you can look at MergeOption.OverwriteChanges when you retrieve the data. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126845/refreshing-data-using-entity-framework

Comment: EF has a complex cache strategy for better performance but that might drive you crazy on some data changes.
Basically, inside your `using` closure EF will fall back to cache unless there is none. For that, every call should be performed with `AsNoTracking`. Sometimes that will crash your code and you'll have to use the `MergeOption`, as pointed out before.

To check if this is a cache issue, create a new context (outside your `using` statement) and try fetch the same data with the `AsNoTracking` option. If it does retrieve data correctly, you'll have to modify your using statement...