# Entity Framework 6 can't auto refresh data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

when i call this code for get row list, ef successfully return row list. when i call again this code data is not refresh. actually database data is changed.

```
        var contacts = (from con in ServerEntities.ContactsQueues
                        select con);
        var rrr = contacts.ToList();
```

Best Regards

Comment: Pls see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126845/refreshing-data-using-entity-framework?rq=1

Comment: this solution doesn't work on ef6.

Comment: You should recreate your context every time you query.. or use the Refresh()  method on the context.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to reload new data every time with ef.

Comment: @EhsanFarahani create a new dbcontext everytime and fetch data .. Or use the Refresh method. see related/linked answers at  the right too